# Hex encoder method producing weird string instead of SHA-256 string

Tags: java, string, tostring

I am new in Java programming.

I want to get sha-256 hash of some given strings.

I am getting:

> 㔴晥㜶晥㜶㔴㄰扡㔴晥㄰扡㌲㌲㌲㄰摣㔴㜶㌲扡扡㌲㄰㄰㌲㜶㜶晥㔴㄰

But Expecting something like:

> 074cfbbad12bade66c92d01142b83c8f2b24030959980151f83972f4575a43e1

Here is my code:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class HelloWorld{

    private static final char[] DIGITS;    
    static {
        char[] arrc;
        char[] arrc2 = arrc = new char[16];
        arrc2[0] = 12592;
        arrc2[1] = 13106;
        arrc2[2] = 13620;
        arrc2[3] = 14134;
        arrc2[4] = 14648;
        arrc2[5] = 25185;
        arrc2[6] = 25699;
        arrc2[7] = 26213;
        DIGITS = arrc;
    }

     public static void main(String []args){
        StringBuilder localStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        localStringBuilder.append(55);
        localStringBuilder.append("market-gap");
        localStringBuilder.append("marjet-gre");
        localStringBuilder.append("1");
        localStringBuilder.append("05/19/1989");
        localStringBuilder.append("6.3.0");
        localStringBuilder.append("0");
        localStringBuilder.append("");
        localStringBuilder.append("en");
        localStringBuilder.append("");
        localStringBuilder.append("00e0533117bb8707");
        String paramString1 = localStringBuilder.toString();

        String strrrr = sha256(paramString1);

        System.out.println(strrrr);
     }

     public static String encodeHex(byte[] arrby) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(arrby.length * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrby.length; ++i) {
            stringBuilder.append(DIGITS[(arrby[i] & 240) >>> 4]);
            stringBuilder.append(DIGITS[arrby[i] & 15]);
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
    public static String sha256(String paramString)
      {
        try
        {
          MessageDigest localMessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
          return encodeHex(localMessageDigest.digest(paramString.getBytes()));
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
          //ThrowableExtension.printStackTrace(e);
        }
        return null;
      }
}
```

What i did wrong here?

Regards

Comment: You are getting chinese characters as you used them in your static block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hex encoder looks very suspicious. How exactly is it supposed to work?

You can try the converter that already exists in the JDK:

```
public static String sha256(String paramString) {
    try {
        MessageDigest localMessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] binaryDigest = localMessageDigest.digest(paramString.getBytes());
        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(binaryDigest);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // ThrowableExtension.printStackTrace(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Edit:

Okay, got it.

Your `DIGITS` values were wrong. Here's a working version:

```
public class HelloWorld {

private static final char[] DIGITS = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder localStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        localStringBuilder.append(55);
        localStringBuilder.append("market-gap");
        localStringBuilder.append("marjet-gre");
        localStringBuilder.append("1");
        localStringBuilder.append("05/19/1989");
        localStringBuilder.append("6.3.0");
        localStringBuilder.append("0");
        localStringBuilder.append("");
        localStringBuilder.append("en");
        localStringBuilder.append("");
        localStringBuilder.append("00e0533117bb8707");
        String paramString1 = localStringBuilder.toString();

        String strrrr = sha256(paramString1);

        System.out.println(strrrr);
    }

    public static String encodeHex(byte[] arrby) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(arrby.length * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrby.length; ++i) {
            stringBuilder.append(DIGITS[(arrby[i] & 0xF0) >>> 4]);
            stringBuilder.append(DIGITS[arrby[i] & 0x0F]);
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public static String sha256(String paramString) {
        try {
            MessageDigest localMessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            return encodeHex(localMessageDigest.digest(paramString.getBytes()));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // ThrowableExtension.printStackTrace(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Also, I changed the ints `240` and `15` to `0xF0` and `0x0F` for readability.

Comment: Yah, it was problem on `DIGITS` . thanks